# How to adjust some OpenMP 3.0 statements so that they can be used in vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, openmp

Here are some openmp 3.0 code:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp single nowait
{
    while(!texture_patches.empty())
    {
        int texture_size = calculate_texture_size(texture_patches, BORDER);
        mve::ByteImage::Ptr texture = mve::ByteImage::create(texture_size, texture_size, 3);
        mve::ByteImage::Ptr validity_mask = mve::ByteImage::create(texture_size, texture_size, 1);
        //...
        //the content of texture_patches changes here
        //...
        #pragma omp task
        dilate_valid_pixel(texture, validity_mask);//has no effects on the content of texture_patches
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
    std::cout << "done. (Took: " << timer.get_elapsed_sec() << "s)" << std::endl;
}
}
```

As is known, vs2010 doesn't support openmp3.0. Could anyone tell me how to adjust the above code so that they can be used in vs2010? Thanks!

Comment: No code shown explicitly modifies `texture_patches` therefore it is not trivial to determine if there is a single pass over its content or items get added dynamically. As long as there is a single pass over it, the `while` loop could be turned into a parallel `for` loop.

Comment: @HristoIliev, the above code is only partial, and texture_patches changes dynamically. I believe while loop can be turned into a parallel for loop, but what about task and taskwait? That is the problem!

Comment: If the while loop could be turned into a parallel for loop, then your problem is already solved. The body of the parallel loop becomes the source of implicit tasks and `taskwait` won't be necessary at all. If `texture_patches` changes dynamically because some task inserts or deletes elements in it, then you are in trouble and parallel for won't work. In that case Intel [Threading Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) would be a better alternative to OpenMP.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code is still not clear to me. But the fact that `taskwait` is located **after** the `while` loop signifies, that `dilate_valid_pixel` has no side effects on the content of `texture_patches`. Therefore, it should be possible to create an array of `(texture, validity_mask)` tuples and then run a parallel loop calling `dilate_valid_pixel` with elements of that array. I will expand that into an answer but you are free not to accept it - it is just hard to put code samples into comments.

Comment: @HristoIliev, thanks a lot! I believe your answer is right. BTW, i edited my problem again. If you're still interested, take a look and thanks again.

Comment: An alternate approach to the problem would simply be to buy an OpenMP compiler for Windows that supports modern OpenMP. Intel (for whom I work) will happily sell you a compiler like that! Depending on how you value your time this could be a cheaper approach...

Comment: Or he could switch to TBB or use GCC for free ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me how `dilate_valid_pixel(texture, validity_mask)` affects the content of `texture_patches`, but the fact that `taskwait` is located **outside** of the `while` loop and the lack of locking directives/calls hint that the `dilate_valid_pixel()` tasks in no way affect the container. What one typically does in such cases is to prepopulate an array of work items and then process the array with a parallel loop. Code follows:

```cpp
// Create work items in serial

std::vector<*WorkItem> work_items;

while(!texture_patches.empty()){
    /* Try to insert each of the texture patches into the texture atlas. */
    for (std::list<TexturePatch>::iterator it = texture_patches.begin(); it != texture_patches.end();){
        TexturePatch texture_patch = *it;
        // ...
        if (bin.insert(&rect)){

            it = texture_patches.erase(it);//Attention!!! texture_patches changes
            remaining_patches--;
        } else {
            it++;
        }
    }
    //#pragma omp task
    //dilate_valid_pixel(texture, validity_mask);
    work_items.push_back(new WorkItem(texture, validity_mask));

    groups.push_back(group);
    material_lib.add_material(group.material_name, texture);
}

// Process the work items in parallel

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < work_items.size(); i++)
    dilate_valid_pixel(work_items[i]->texture, work_items[i]->validity_mask);

std::cout << "done. (Took: " << timer.get_elapsed_sec() << "s)" << std::endl;
```

Freeing up the memory for work items not shown. The original task code retained in comments.

One important aspect: if `dilate_valid_pixel()` does not always take the same amount of time to complete, then add `schedule(dynamic,1)` clause to the `parallel for` construct and play with the chunk size (the `1`) in order to achieve the best performance.

This code is not exactly equivalent to the one using explicit tasks since all tasks are created first and then executed while the original code creates tasks in parallel with their execution, i.e. the code above will perform from a bit worse (if tasks creation is very fast) to a lot worse (if tasks creation takes a long time) than the original code.